# tkinter window not wide enough to display window title

Tags: python, tkinter, root, title

Is there a 'standard' way of ensuring that the displayed window is wide enough to display the window title?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root_f = tk.Frame(root)
root.title('Long Window Title Containing Much Text')
text_f = tk.Frame(root_f)
text_l = tk.Label(text_f, text='Short text')

root_f.grid()
text_f.grid()
text_l.grid()

root.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(100, 100))
root.mainloop()
root.quit()
```

When I use the winfo method to get the width of the root (or text) frames they give the size of the text not the size of a window wide enough to display the whole window title.

I know it has to be something simple, but I can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: Running on MacOS X with Python 3.4.3 everything works like a charm. Did you try to comment `root.geometry()` line in order to enable automatic window scaling?

Comment: Thanks Albert. It's interesting though on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 running python 3.4, all I get is a very tiny window just big enough to hold the text 'Short text'. Strange. Thanks though.

Comment: Ohh, you're definitely right. Didn't see that. I thought you got problems showing the text `Short Text` . The window's title is not visible at my system, too. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no standard way. Tkinter has no way of knowing how long the title is on the titlebar. The OS / window manager has completely control of that portion of the window and doesn't expose any platform-independent way of getting at that information.

You would have to know not only the font used by the OS for window titles, but also whether there were any other decorations (eg: buttons, images, etc) that appear in the title area.

If you're fine with making assumptions that the font is the same as the default tkinter font, you can use tkinter's ability to measure the length of a string in a given font with the `measure` method of a font object.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, the font of all wisdom as usual :). It does seem a little odd to me that there isn't someway of tkinter knowing this, but as you can see from above I am finding a way of doing this. Thanks again.